# Paypal unreachable or bug on my part?

Tags: php, paypal

I basically followed the code at https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

I changed a few things, but nothing seems to be working. For example- directly visiting:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=EC-0MV58959Y5305423G

Gives me an error in chrome, and by looking at the headers with curl it redirects me to:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutincontextinitflow?token=EC-0MV58959Y5305423G

Which again gives me an error in chrome. What's strange is that my code worked perfectly before... is only failing now.

One thing I did not integrate via the paypal wizard code is the PROXY_HOST stuff... seemed optional, but should I set that? In what circumstance would one set that? It's the line like:

```
if($USE_PROXY)
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST. ":" . $PROXY_PORT);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sandbox, bug was on paypal's part... but just an accounts thing (not programming). I had to either recreate new sandbox accounts or log in to the sandbox account (which must have triggered some sort of refresh on their side)

For the live account, I simply hadn't activated digital goods for express checkout. Calling them up fixed that.